# Will apache kill a PHP process if the user closes the connection

Tags: php, apache, process

I have the following argument with a colleague of mine. I stated that Apache won't kill a PHP process if the user closes the connection (closes the window or tab for example). While my colleague stated the opposite - that Apache will kill the PHP process if the TCP connection closes.

We did tested it and it looked like I was right, but I am not sure about how this works.

Comment: I like this question.  When I was watching a server, a problem was Apache liking to hang around too damn long.  Hadn't thought of PHP being a contributor!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First up: you are right ;-)

What happens is, that your browser chooses to ignore the answer and move on. It does not send the apache some sort of 'I quit you can stop'.

The process will run until it is finished.
So if you code an endless loop, closing the browser window will not save you. The script max execution time eventually will, but that is another topic.

Comment: Nice.  So the lesson is don't test endless loops with max execution disabled? lmao

Comment: Yeah, that is one of the lessons ;-)

Comment: Guys you always have `kill`.

Comment: How does the PHP `ignore_user_abort` setting relate to this?